# Como funciona o método cloneNode?

Tags: javascript, clone

Eu estou criando uma aplicação e preciso copiar um elemento para criá-lo novamente na página HTML. Pesquisando na internet, eu encontrei o método `cloneNode`. Eu quero saber o seguinte:

- Como o método funciona?
- Ele copia somente o estilo do objeto ou seus eventos também? O quão profundo é a clonagem?
- Existe um parâmetro para realizar apenas a cópia dos estilos e atributos, porém descartando qualquer evento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente, [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) copia o *node*, mas o clone não tem um *parent* e não fará parte do documento, a menos que você o adicione em algum lugar.

Ele recebe um parâmetro *booleano* indicando se a cópia deve ser *deep* ou não.

No caso da cópia não-*deep*, apenas o *node* e seus atributos são copiados. Nem mesmo o texto que está dentro da **tag** é copiado. No caso de eventos, apenas aqueles definidos *inline* serão copiados. Já aqueles adicionados por `addEventListener` não o serão.

Se a cópia for *deep*, todos os nós filhos são copiados. Mas os eventos adicionados por `addEventListener` continuarão não sendo copiados.

Exemplo:

```js
document.querySelector('#paragrafo').addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('cliquei no paragrafo');
});

function clonar(deep) {
    let clone = document.querySelector('#paragrafo').cloneNode(deep);
    // remover o id, senão você terá mais de um elemento com o mesmo id
    clone.removeAttribute('id');
    document.querySelector('#main').appendChild(clone);
}
```

```css
p {
    padding: 2px;
    color: blue;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#paragrafo {
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <p id="paragrafo" onclick="alert(`inline onclick ${this.id}`)">lorem <b>ipsum</b> etc</p>
</div>

<form>
  <input name="deep" type="checkbox">Deep clone<br>
  <input type="button" value="clonar parágrafo" onclick="clonar(this.form.deep.checked)">
</form>
```

Coloquei uma borda ao redor dos parágrafos para que seja possível visualizar nos casos de cópias não-*deep*, já que nesses casos o parágrafo não terá nenhum texto (somente a tag vazia). Mas repare que mesmo assim os clones mantêm o evento definido por `onclick` (mas não tem o que foi definido por `addEventListener`).

---

Outro detalhe citado na documentação é que o valor *default* do parâmetro `deep`, quando não especificado, pode variar de acordo com a implementação (em versões antigas de alguns *browsers* era `true`, mas nas especificações mais novas passou a ser `false`). Por isso o mais garantido é sempre passar o parâmetro de acordo com o que você precisa.

---

Sobre os estilos, nos exemplos que usei não tive problemas, mas pesquisando encontrei [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1848445) dizendo que os [*computed styles*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) não eram copiados. Se for esse o seu caso, a solução está nas respostas de lá.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mas então como eu posso copiar um elemento por completo? Quero dizer, ter dois objetos idênticos, em estilo, textos, elementos filhos e eventos (incluindo listeners) mas sendo diferentes na memória?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 [Pelo que pesquisei](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+clone+copy+all+event), nativamente não dá pra copiar todos os *event listeners* (alguns sugerem guardar isso em algum lugar e depois adicionar manualmente, ou usar jQuery, que usa um mecanismo à parte para clonar e consegue copiar os *listeners*). E só lembrando que ao clonar com `cloneNode`, o clone já é um "objeto diferente na memória" :-)

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/545223/112052

Comment: Depois de quase 2 anos... kkkk

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Tenho culpa se a outra pergunta foi feita tanto tempo depois? :-)