# Qual a diferença entre "structuredClone()" e o operador spread ("...") ao se clonar objetos em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, funções, objetos, clone

Analisei um código que vou recriar uma parte dele abaixo, onde foi feita uma cópia de uma RegEx, usando uma função *built-in* (nem sabia que era) chamada `structuredClone`:

```js
//  trecho de exemplo
const reg = /\d/g
const copiedReg = structuredClone(reg)
// ===========

console.log('original', reg)
console.log('copia', copiedReg)
console.log(reg === copiedReg)
```

Resolvi fazer uns testes com outros objetos:

```js
const original = { foo: 'bar', baz: true }
const copied = structuredClone(original)

console.log(original)
console.log(copied)
console.log(original === copied) // false, pois foi feita cópia de objeto
```

O que não entendi é que o comportamento parece o mesmo do uso do operador *spread*:

```js
const original = { foo: 'bar', baz: true }
const copied = { ...original } // uso de spread

console.log(original)
console.log(copied)
console.log(original === copied) // false, pois foi feita cópia de objeto
```

- Qual ou quais as diferenças no uso dessa função `structuredClone()` e no uso do operador *spread* (`...`) para se copiar objetos?
- Esta função `structuredClone` só existe para se realizar copias de RegEx?

---

Achei curioso e válido o uso dessa função, pois não sabia como realizar cópia de RegEx de maneira simples e com [menos código](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-clone-a-given-regular-expression-in-javascript/).

---

**Obs**: Atenção ao comentário do @bfavaretto sobre o `structuredClone`:

> alguns browsers, segundo a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone#browser_compatibility), parecem não suportar o `structuredClone` ainda, notadamente o Safari (tanto para OSX quanto para iOS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A diferença é que [o *spread* faz uma *shallow copy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals), enquanto o `structuredClone` faz uma [*deep copy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy).

Ou seja, se o objeto sendo clonado possui alguma propriedade que é uma referência (por exemplo, algum outro objeto ou um array), o *spread* usa a mesma referência, enquanto o `structuredClone` cria uma cópia deste.

Veja a diferença, primeiro com *spread*:

```js
const original = {
  nome: "Fulano", idade: 42,
  dados: {
    telefone: '999-9999', email: 'fulano@mail.com'
  }
};

const shallowCopy = { ...original };
// mudar dados da propriedade "dados" da cópia
shallowCopy.dados.telefone = '111-1111';
// original também foi alterado
console.log(original);
// pois a referência ao objeto interno "dados" é a mesma
console.log(shallowCopy.dados === original.dados); // true
```

E agora com `structuredClone`:

```js
const original = {
  nome: "Fulano", idade: 42,
  dados: {
    telefone: '999-9999', email: 'fulano@mail.com'
  }
};
const deepCopy = structuredClone(original);
// mudar dados da propriedade "dados" da cópia
deepCopy.dados.telefone = '111-1111';
// original não é alterado
console.log(original);
// pois a referência ao objeto interno "dados" não é a mesma
console.log(deepCopy.dados === original.dados); // false
```

Repare que o telefone do objeto original é alterado somente no primeiro caso, pois foi feita uma *shallow copy* (somente a referência ao mesmo objeto `dados` foi copiada), enquanto no segundo caso ele criou uma cópia deste).

---

Existem outras diferenças. Algumas coisas não funcionam com `structuredClone` e estão [listadas na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#things_that_dont_work_with_structured_clone), como por exemplo, funções:

```js
const original = {
  nome: "Fulano",
  fazAlgo: function() { console.log(this.nome); }
};
shallowCopy = { ...original };
shallowCopy.fazAlgo(); // Fulano

// ERRO (DataCloneError)
const deepCopy = structuredClone(original);
```

Entre outras coisas que não funcionam, estão: *DOM nodes* (para estes existe o [método  `cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)), a propriedade `lastIndex` da uma `RegExp`, *getters*/*setters*, entre outros.

Outra diferença é que `structuredClone` possui um segundo parâmetro opcional, que é uma lista de objetos que são transferidos para a cópia em vez de clonados (não pode ser qualquer objeto, precisa ser um *transferable object*, ver a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Transferable_objects) para mais detalhes).

---

Outra diferença interessante é a forma como eles lidam com referências circulares:

```js
// objeto aponta para ele mesmo
const original = { name: "MDN" };
original.itself = original;

// shallow copy, "itself" continua apontando para o objeto original
const shallowCopy = { ...original };
console.log(shallowCopy.itself === shallowCopy); // false
console.log(shallowCopy.itself === original); // true

// deep copy, "itself" aponta para o próprio clone
const deepCopy = structuredClone(original);
console.log(deepCopy.itself === deepCopy); // true
console.log(deepCopy.itself === original); // false
```

Na *shallow copy*, a propriedade `itself` continua apontando para o objeto original (já que ele copia a referência). Na *deep copy* ele faz com que `itself` aponte para o próprio clone (que seria o "esperado", pois se no objeto original, a propriedade `itself` aponta para ele mesmo, esta característica é mantida no clone).

Comment: Muito bom, eu também não conhecia essa função. Só uma observação: alguns browsers, segundo a MDN, parecem não suportar o structuredClone ainda, notadamente o Safari (tanto para OSX quanto para iOS).

Comment: @bfavaretto boa observação. Obrigado por informar